# TypeError: to_sql() when inserting into MySQL database with pd.DataFrame.to_sql

Tags: python, pandas, mysql-python

I am trying to write a simple Python prog to create a DataFrame with Pandas, delete some of the columns in the DataFrame and then use pd.DataFrame.to_sql to insert the values into a pre-existing MySQL table. I am using sqlalchemy & pymysql to connect to MySQL database. However, I get the following error "TypeError: to_sql() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'"

The DataFrame that is created looks like:

```
           Unnamed: 0.1  Row    number    Date      Length      Position
0              0         1      23065  03/16/20     28.485     -14.438
1              2         3      23060  03/16/20     26.596      -2.135
```

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as db
import pymysql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = db.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://user:pass@host:port/db')
connection = engine.raw_connection()
cursor = connection.cursor()
print(engine)
df=pd.read_csv(r"C:\\Users\\nos.csv")
df.drop(df.columns[[0,1]], axis=1)
print(df)
into_db=pd.DataFrame.to_sql(name='schema.tablename', con=engine, index=False, index_label=True, if_exists='append')
connection.execute(into_db)
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
```

Any help is gratefully received.